# Spark Scala - store query result as scala integer type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to take the result of a spark sql query, which is expected to be a single column/row integer value, and store it in a scala variable to use further down. Here is my code:

```
val max_val_frame = spark.sql(f"""select max(val) as max_val from temp_table_1""");

//code to cast max_val_frame to integer

var max_val = //casted value from max_val_frame

var init_val = 1;

while (init_val <= max_val) {

    print(init_val);

init_val = init_val + 1;

}
```

Does anyone know how I can cast that spark dataframe object to a scala integer?

I have tried a number of things, including casting the entire dataframe to a string first, then an int, but it does not properly extract the value as an int.

Comment: Collect your data frame as a list and use its single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```scala
val max_val = max_val_frame.collect().head.getInt(0)
```

The first `.head` or `(0)` takes the first row, then you can use `getInt(0)` or `getDouble(0)` to parse element with index `0` of the row.